# Dynamic Colours In Illustrator Chart

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, chart-design

Is there any way to control the colours used in an illustrator chart dynamically?

For example, I know I can make a pie chart and use the Direct Selection tool to change the colours of the slices, but is there any way of specifying the colours in the same way as the ratio is specified.

Essentially I need a way to do:

```
0.5 #FF0000
0.2 #00FF00
0.3 #0000FF
```

And have the chart update the colours.

Comment: Depends on how broadly you define possible.

Comment: Some relevant discussion around this post in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=30830468#30830468)

Comment: @joojaa can you provide some context for the link please.